# Weird error NSAssert

Tags: objective-c, nsassert

I can't figure out why I get

```
use of undeclared identifier _cmd  did you mean rcmd
```

on the line where NSAssert is.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int x = 10;

    NSAssert(x > 11, @"x should be greater than %d", x);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Inside every Objective-c method there are two hidden variables `id self` and `SEL _cmd`

so

```
- (void)foo:(id)bar;
```

is really

```
void foo(id self, SEL _cmd, id bar) { ... }
```

and when you call

```
[someObject foo:@"hello world"]
```

it is actually

```
foo( someObject, @selector(foo), @"hello world")
```

If you cmd-click on NSAssert to jump to it's definition you will see that it is a macro that uses the hidden  _cmd variable of the method you are calling it from. This means that if you are not inside an Objective-c method (perhaps you are in 'main'), therefore you don't have a _cmd argument, you cannot use NSAssert.

Instead you can use the alternative NSCAssert.

Comment: Really good explanation... and I learnt something about objective-C !

Answer (score 31):

`NSAssert` [is only meant to be used within Objective-C methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html).  Since `main` is a C function, use `NSCAssert` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

NSAssert(x > 11, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x should be greater than %d", x]);

with

NSCAssert(x > 11, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x should be greater than %d", x]);

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your string in a NSString class if you want to use format parameters. That is because `@""` is a default constructor for a plain NSString. The way it is written now gives a third parameter to the `NSAssert` function and messes with it.

```
NSAssert(x > 11, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"x should be greater than %d", x]);
```

Comment: I get the same error If I change the code to NSAssert(x > 11, @"x should be greater than");

Comment: The answer from @highlycaffeinated is the one I reached just about now.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR - stick with stray NSAssert() - don't try this in production**

Original code

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int x = 10;

    NSAssert(x > 11, @"x should be greater than %d", x);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Build failure

```
 Compiling file hello.m ...
hello.m:9:5: error: use of undeclared identifier '_cmd'
    NSAssert(x > 11, @"x should be greater than %d", x);
    ^
/usr/include/Foundation/NSException.h:450:32: note: expanded from macro 'NSAssert'
        handleFailureInMethod: _cmd                             \
                               ^
hello.m:9:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'self'
/usr/include/Foundation/NSException.h:451:17: note: expanded from macro 'NSAssert'
        object: self                                            \
                ^
2 errors generated.
```

Based on [explanation by @hooleyhoop @Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9739924/) and
[id](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/id?language=occ)
[self](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418954-self?language=occ)
[SEL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/sel?language=occ),
the following dirty hack may be applicable if I insist on using
[`NSAssert()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsassert) instead of
[`NSCAssert()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscassert)

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int x = 10;

    // Dirty hack
    SEL _cmd=NULL;
    NSObject *self=NULL;

    NSAssert(x > 11, @"x should be greater than %d", x);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Build & run

```
 Compiling file hello.m ...
 Linking tool hello ...
2021-03-04 21:25:58.035 hello[39049:39049] hello.m:13  Assertion failed in (null)(instance), method (null).  x should be greater than 10
./obj/hello: Uncaught exception NSInternalInconsistencyException, reason: hello.m:13  Assertion failed in (null)(instance), method (null).  x should be greater than 10
```

Hooray it works! But, alas, please stay away from it :)